# incompatible pointer types: UIImage and UIImageView

Tags: ios, sprite

`Sprite *shipViewTemp = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:(UIImage *) ship];`

This is the only error in my code, can anyone help?

#### xcode says

> incompatible pointer types

Comment: You are allocating a UIImageView but assigning it to a Sprite pointer

Comment: Change `Sprite` to `UIImageView`.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the full error that Xcode is giving you. Generally, the error/warning will be telling you exactly what's wrong. In this case the full error is likely:

`Incompatible pointer types initializing 'Sprite' with an expression of type 'UIImageView *'`

In this case, it's telling you that you're trying to assign an instance of `UIImageView` to a variable that is expecting a `Sprite`. (In my screenshot below I used `NSString`, but you'd see something similar with `Sprite`.)

[image]